# What is Lamè mode?

Tags: resonance, stress-strain, continuum-mechanics, vibrations, normal-modes

I am trying to read some of the articles that says Lamè mode.

But I can't find in google that describes Lamè mode.

Can anyone quote good reference for this term?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but it appears in the context of ultrasonic detection schemes, and Lamè mode quartz resonators. See http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2783&context=qnde  and http://www.google.com/patents/US6545394